# OpenCV/C++ - generate variables/vectors? Detecting multiple different objects

Tags: c++, opencv, parameter-passing

I have an OpenCV program that takes in a template image and compares it to a video feed. I'm looking to be able to compare multiple template images to the video feed but I'm having trouble getting my head around the logic required.

I have a thread for video capture which takes in the frames, converts them to gray and returns them to `main()`.

```
Mat captureThread() {
  if(captureOpen == false){
    img_scene = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
  }
  while(1) {
    image = cvQueryFrame(img_scene);
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    return gray;
  }
}
```

After this a pre-processing function is then called where the template images are passed for feature point detection. These are read in by command line arguments and are passed like so:

```
  for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    img_object = imread( argv[i], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    preProcessing(img_object, argv[i]);
  }

void preProcessing(Mat img_object, char* objectName) {
  featureDetector->detect(img_object, keypointsObject);
  featureExtractor->compute(img_object, keypointsObject, descriptorsObject);
}
```

As you can see the keypoints and descriptors are assigned to variables (Vector and Mat) which are then used in the live processing thread to compare them to the video feed.

```
Mat processingThread(Mat gray, Mat img_object) {
  featureDetector->detect(gray, keypoints);
  featureExtractor->compute(gray, keypoints, descriptors);
  Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new BFMatcher(NORM_HAMMING, false));
  std::vector<DMatch> matches;
  if(descriptorsObject.type() == descriptors.type() && descriptorsObject.cols == descriptors.cols) {
    matcher->match(descriptorsObject, descriptors, matches);
  }
  ...
  ...
  return imgMatches;
}
```

The rest of `main()`:

```
  while(1) {
    thread t1(captureThread); 
    t1.join();
    captureOpen = true;
    thread t2(processingThread, gray, img_object);
    t2.join();
    imshow("Output", imgMatches);
    key = cvWaitKey(5);
    if (char(key) == 27) {
      break;
    }  
  }
```

What approach should I take for being able to pre-process multiple template images and then compare them to the main video feed to see if any are found? Would it be possible to generate new variables/vectors for each image passed in?

EDIT:
So far I've each image that is being passed in held in an array along with keypoints and descriptors:

```
Mat imageArray[2];
Mat descriptorsArray[2];
vector<KeyPoint> keypointArray[2];
```

Comment: please do no more use cvCaptureFromCAM (that's from the outdated c-api), but cv::VideoCapture

Comment: yes, you can have vectors or arrays of anything. but rather re-think your threading approach. creating/releasing a capture object per image is a total rotten idea. better have one instance around for the whole lifetime of your program.